# Getting 502 Bad Gateway currently for url: https://jcenter.bintray.com

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Getting following error currently while building the android project in android studio.

Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Answer (score 4):

It is because of 
Bintray is having some problems. 
You can check status [here](https://status.bintray.com/)

[image]